# Proving a lower bound for large enough $n$

Tags: limits

Given that $n,s, ~and ~r$ are positive integers such that $n>s>r \geq 3$, prove that for large enough $n$
$$\binom{s-2}{r}+(n-s+2)\binom{s-2}{r-1}$$  is at least $$\frac{n}{r}\left(\binom {s-2}{r-1} + \binom {s-3}{r-2} \right)$$
Can someone help me with this?

The calculation is confusing. I reach a place when I just can't compare the terms anymore.

Comment: What have you tried?  It seems clear to pull some factors out of the combinations at the start to make them look like the combinations at the end.

Comment: Did that but still I'm stuck. I'm retrying

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to showing that

$$r\left(\binom{s-2}r+(n-s+2)\binom{s-2}{r-1}\right)\tag{1}$$

is at least

$$n\left(\binom{s-2}{r-1}+\binom{s-3}{r-2}\right)\,.\tag{2}$$

Suppose that you have a pool of $n$ athletes, $s-2$ of whom are women. $(1)$ is the number of ways to choose a team of $r$ from this pool and designate one of them captain if you are required to pick at least $r-1$ women: either you pick $r$ women, or you pick $r-1$ women and one man, and then you pick one of these $r$ people to be captain.

$(2)$ is a bit more complicated. There are $\binom{s-2}{r-1}$ ways to pick $r-1$ women and appoint the shortest of them provisional captain. (I will assume that no two people in the pool are exactly the same height.) There are $\binom{s-3}{r-2}$ ways to appoint the tallest woman provisional captain and choose $r-2$ more women for the team. In each case we end up with $r-1$ women, one of whom is provisionally designated the team captain, and all of these partial teams are distinct, if only by virtue of having different provisional captains. Finally, there are $n$ ways to choose one more person for the team. If that person is already on the team, replace her with the tallest man in the pool and make him the captain; otherwise, add her to the team and confirm the provisional captain as captain. No two of the resulting teams have both the same members and the same captain, so $(2)$ gives the number of such teams.

Clearly in this interpretation every combination of team and captain counted by $(2)$ is also counted by $(1)$, and this immediately implies the desired inequality.